# ImagesService.getServingUrl fails with IllegalArgumentException and no error message for Cloud Storage object

Tags: google-app-engine

Here's the code:

```
public static String getNotFoundUrl(int size) {
  try {
    BlobKey blob_key = BLOB_STORE.createGsBlobKey("/gs/web_content/placeholder_img.png");

    // Simple Test to make sure blob_key points at the right thing.
    byte[] image_data = BLOB_STORE.fetchData(blob_key, 0, 100);
    Application.getLogger().warning(new String(image_data));
    // This parts works and gets the first 100 bytes.

    ServingUrlOptions opts = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blob_key);
    if(size > 0) opts.imageSize(size);
    return IMAGES_SERVICE.getServingUrl(opts);
  } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Application.getLogger().warning("Unable to serve placeholder image from Cloud Storage.");
    Application.getLogger().warning(e.getMessage());
    Application.logException(e);
    return "/placeholder_img.png";
  }
}
```

I have also tried using

```
ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName
```

and got the same results.

In my mind the blob_key is definitely valid because I'm able to use

```
BlobstoreService.fetchData
```

to read the first 100 bytes and it's not throwing an exception and is successfully reading the data.

The only thing that's different about this then other situations is the file I"m trying to access was uploaded via the Cloud Console Web UI rather then through the AppEngine SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was permissions. Make sure that your application has permissions to the cloud storage project that you're trying to access.

Comment: I had a similar problem when switching to bucket level permissions.  I received an ImagesServiceFailureException with no message.  Switching back to Fine-grained/ Object-level ACLs resolved the problem.  My bucket permissions were world-readable, but it is possible that there is some set of bucket-level permissions that would avoid the error.